# Unable to compare empty Strings

Tags: java, android, if-statement, syntax, logical-operators

can you check why this code jumps to else with the conditions like e1="1", e2="2", e3=""

```
if (e1=="" || e2=="" || e3==""){
                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                CharSequence text = "Fill in all required fields!";
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER|Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                toast.show();
            }
            else {
                m=Integer.parseInt(e1);
                std=Integer.parseInt(e2);
                nhv=Integer.parseInt(e3);
            rsl=((std*std)*((t1+t2)*(t1+t2)))/((m-nhv)*(m-nhv));
            if (Math.round(rsl) < rsl) {
                rsl = Math.round(rsl) +1; 
            } 
            else {
                rsl=Math.round(rsl);
            }
            et4.setText(""+rsl);
        }
```

Comment: For strings use .equals not ==

Comment: @iamnotmaynard: This is a little different since it is Android

Comment: @GIJoe ,not sure if serious or just joking ,its Java, it doesn't matter where you run it.

Comment: @SteveL: I am not joking. Android SDK is not the same

Comment: @SteveL: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Java_and_Android_API

Comment: @GIJoe I just read that entry. It says nothing about `Strings`, and there's no reason to believe it's any different from regular Java in that regard. Indeed, judging by your own answer, the behavior is the same. Thus, Android or not, I'd say this is a duplicate.

Comment: @GIJoe ,Seems that you are correct about the differences, dalvik doesn't use Java SE library but a "clone" of it, but it still uses a pool for the strings ,so in this case there is no difference at all at how you compare the Strings

Comment: @SteveL: There is a difference.. can't use .isEmpty for instance... there are better ways than just comparing it per the link above

Comment: @GIJoe What can't use `isEmpty()`? It's a standard part of the `String` class.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard: Not until Android 2.3

Comment: @GIJoe I mean it's a standard part of Java (I suppose since 1.6). Don't know about Android; your own answer uses that method (I see you state "available in Android 2.3", though you could be more clear that it is not available before that). It is also not necessary, as skiwi's answer gives (IMO) the best, most versatile, Java-vs.-Android–agnostic solution: comparing in a `null`-safe way against the empty string using `equals()`. In any case, OP's code is failing precisely for the reason given in the linked question, hence marked as duplicate.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard: the question was labeled Android.

Comment: My way is null safe and ideal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `String` comparison you need to use `.equals()`, like `e1.equals("")`, or argubly better `"".equals(e1)`.
The second form is argubly better as it can never throw a `NullPointerException`.

Keep in mind that only primitives `int`, etc. should be compared with `==`, everything else should be compared with `Object#equals(Object)`.

Comment: actually, the right way is to use `isEmpty`, if using Android 2.3 or greater or `TextUtils`

Comment: +1 I'd say your second form is _inarguably_ better, as it is inherently null-safe.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard: both of my examples are null safe. TextUtils.isEmpty checks for null. You can look at the code yourself in Android.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use:

```
if (e1.isEmpty() || e2.isEmpty() || e3.isEmpty())
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are checking if your `String` is null or empty, [use the method](http://www.androidzeitgeist.com/2012/12/string-is-empty.html) designed for it:

```
if (myString != null && !myString.isEmpty()) 
{ 

// doSomething

}
```

Anything else is prone to bugs or just isn't clear.

Note: This is available in Android 2.3.

Google also provides this via `TextUtils`:

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(value))
{
    // do something
}
```

Internally [TextUtils.isEmpty()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/text/TextUtils.java#TextUtils.isEmpty%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) checks if the length of the String is 0 (and does a null check).